# aws sdk not listing load balancers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, aws-sdk

I'm trying to list my load balancers in us-east-1 (US East (N. Virginia)). I can see two load balancers front the web console (under EC2 > Load Balancing > Load Balancers) But if I run:

```
AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var elb = new AWS.ELBv2({
  accessKeyId: '<accessKeyId>',
  secretAccessKey: '<secretAccessKey>',
  region: 'us-east-1'
});

elb.describeLoadBalancers({}, (e, r) => console.log('error', e, 'result', r))
```

this logs:

```
error null result { ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: '<some-long-id>' }, LoadBalancers: [] }
```

Comment: Your [rubber duck](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) has let you down.  `ec2.describeImages` doesn't list load balancers, does it?  Are you sure this is the code that generates that response?

Comment: what a bad copy paste! I've updated the question with the accurate code...

Comment: Are your balancers "Classic" load balancers or "Application" load balancers?  It looks like [ELBv2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ELBv2.html) is *only* for the 2nd generation balancers, the Application Load Balancer (ALB), not Classic.

Comment: You're right, I was using classic load balancers and `ELBv2` is indeed for Application load balancers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ELBv2` class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ELBv2.html) in the Javascript SDK is not a replacement for the `ELB` class.  `ELBv2` is for 2nd generation ELB -- Application Load Balancers, while `ELB` is used for 1st generation ELB, now referred to as Classic Load Balancers.

The two generations of ELB do have some overlap in their features and capabilities, but both generations offer capabilities that the other does not -- Classic LB can do SSL/TLS offloading for non-HTTP services, Application LB can't; Application LB can choose back-ends based on HTTP request paths and speak HTTP/2 and route to multiple ports on a single instance, Classic LB can't.

The two generations are very different in their configuration options, and presumably that is why there's a separate interface for interrogating and manipulating two different types of balancers.

Comment: Thanks! I wished the SDK and documentation had made it more obvious. The SDK could be ApplicationELB or something, especially since according to what you're saying it's not really a v2 in the sense that it's missing some features that the classic ELB offers. And the documentation only mentions the application part in the methods descriptions, but should have a big header :)